# Can you help me find my issue please? My variable is not changing after a collision

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision

I am still a beginner and I am trying to use classes more often. I just ran into a problem and I have been trying to figure it out for hours now. When the enemy attacks my planet, my planet's value should go down by however much the fleet's value is. If my planet's value goes under 0, my planet should become the enemy's planet. However, when the enemy's fleet collide with my planet, the value of my planet goes up and the owner variable stays the same. I believe my mistake is somewhere in the update function of my fleet Class.I tried to output a lot of print statements from the code so I can see the state of each variable each loop. Results, the player's planet does not change owner, but I do see the planet's value go down. Also if you guys have any suggestions to help me with other stuff I would appreciate the help. Oh and my colours are hard-coded I know, it is a temporary thing.

```
import sys
import math
import pygame

screen_size = (640, 480)
fps = 60

class Planet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    ''''''

    def __init__(self, x, y, value, owner = 'free', color = (0, 0, 255)):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.value = value
        self.owner = owner
        self.color = color

        self.grow = False
        self.selected = False
        self.text = str(self.value)

    def update(self):
        if self.grow == True:
            self.value += 1
            self.grow = False
        self.text = str(self.value)
        if self.owner == 'player':
            color = (0, 255, 0)
        elif self.owner == 'free':
            color = (0, 0, 255)
        elif self.owner == 'enemy':
            color = (255, 0, 0)
        if self.selected:
            color = (255, 0, 255)
        self.image.fill(color)

    def drawValue(self):
        textToScreen(screen, self.text, self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery)

class Fleet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, value, owner, home, target):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((16, 16))
        self.image.fill((255, 0, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.value = value
        self.owner = owner
        self.text = str(self.value)
        self.home = home
        self.target = target
        self.speed = 2

    def update(self):
        self.text = str(self.value)

        for planet in playerplanets: #fleet collision with
            if planet.rect.collidepoint(self.rect.x, self.rect.y):
                if self.home != planet.rect:
                    if self.owner == 'player':
                        planet.value += self.value
                    elif self.owner == 'enemy':
                        planet.value -= self.value
                        if planet.value <= 0:
                            playerplanets.remove(planet)
                            planet.owner = 'enemy'
                            enemyplanets.add(planet)
                            #planet.value = planet.value - (planet.value * 2)
                    self.kill()

        for planet in freeplanets:
            if planet.rect.collidepoint(self.rect.x, self.rect.y):
                planet.value -= self.value
                if planet.value <= 0:
                    planet.value = planet.value - (planet.value * 2)
                    freeplanets.remove(planet)
                    if self.owner == 'player':
                        planet.owner = 'player'
                        playerplanets.add(planet)
                    elif self.owner == 'enemy':
                        planet.owner = 'enemy'
                        enemyplanets.add(planet)
                self.kill()

        for planet in enemyplanets:
            if planet.rect.collidepoint(self.rect.x, self.rect.y):
                if self.home != planet.rect:
                    planet.value -= self.value
                    if planet.value <= 0:
                        planet.value = planet.value - (planet.value * 2)
                        enemyplanets.remove(planet)
                        planet.owner = 'player'
                        playerplanets.add(planet)


        dx, dy = self.rect.centerx - self.target[0], self.rect.centery - self.target[1]
        dist = math.hypot(dx, dy)
        if dist == 0:
            dist = 1
        else:
            dx, dy = dx / dist, dy / dist
        self.rect.centerx -= dx * self.speed
        self.rect.centery -= dy * self.speed



    def drawValue(self):
        textToScreen(screen, self.text, self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery)


def main():
    global screen, clock, timer, homeplanets, playerplanets, freeplanets, enemyplanets, allplanets, playerfleets, enemyfleets, allfleets
    pygame.init()

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_size), 0)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    timer = 0

    homeplanets = pygame.sprite.Group()
    playerplanets = pygame.sprite.Group()
    freeplanets = pygame.sprite.Group()
    enemyplanets = pygame.sprite.Group()
    allplanets = pygame.sprite.Group()

    playerfleets = pygame.sprite.Group()
    enemyfleets = pygame.sprite.Group()
    allfleets = pygame.sprite.Group()

    background = (200, 200, 200)

    planet01 = Planet(50, 50, 100, 'player', (0, 255, 0))
    planet02 = Planet(100, 200, 50, 'free', (0, 0, 255))
    planet03 = Planet(300, 100, 200, 'enemy', (255, 0, 0))


    homeplanets.add(planet01)
    playerplanets.add(planet01)
    allplanets.add(planet01)

    freeplanets.add(planet02)
    allplanets.add(planet02)

    enemyplanets.add(planet03)
    allplanets.add(planet03)


    while True:

        processTimer()
        processInput()
        processAI()

        allplanets.update()
        allfleets.update()

        screen.fill(background)
        allplanets.draw(screen)
        allfleets.draw(screen)

        for planet in allplanets:
            planet.drawValue()
        for fleet in allfleets:
            fleet.drawValue()


        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(fps)

        #TEST
        for planet in allplanets:
            print planet.owner

def processTimer():
    global timer
    timer += 1
    if timer == 100:
        for planet in allplanets:
            planet.grow = True
        timer = 0

def processInput():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mousex, mousey = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            if event.button == 1:
                processLeftClicked(mousex, mousey)
            elif event.button == 3:
                processRightClicked(mousex, mousey)

def processAI():
    for eplanet in enemyplanets:
        if eplanet.value > 10:
            for pplanet in playerplanets:
                if eplanet.value / 2 > pplanet.value + 10:
                    target = pplanet.rect.center
                    x = eplanet.rect.x
                    y = eplanet.rect.y
                    value = eplanet.value / 2
                    home = eplanet.rect

                    eplanet.value = eplanet.value / 2

                    fleet = Fleet(x, y, value, 'enemy', home, target)
                    enemyfleets.add(fleet)
                    allfleets.add(fleet)

def processLeftClicked(mousex, mousey):
    for planet in playerplanets:
        if planet.rect.collidepoint((mousex, mousey)):
            if planet.selected == True:
                planet.selected = False
            elif planet.selected == False:
                planet.selected = True

def processRightClicked(mousex, mousey):
    for planet_ in allplanets:
        if planet_.rect.collidepoint((mousex, mousey)):
            planet_.selected = False
            target = planet_.rect.center
            for planet in playerplanets:
                if planet.selected == True:
                    if planet.value != 0:
                        x = planet.rect.x
                        y = planet.rect.y
                        value = planet.value / 2
                        home = planet.rect
                        if value == 0:
                            value = 1

                        planet.value = planet.value / 2

                        fleet = Fleet(x, y, value, 'player', home, target)
                        playerfleets.add(fleet)
                        allfleets.add(fleet)



def textToScreen(screen, text, x = 100, y = 100, text_size = 15, text_color = (0, 0, 0), font_type = 'freesans.ttf'):
    try:    
        font = pygame.font.SysFont(font_type, text_size)
        text = str(text)
        text = font.render(text, True, text_color)
        text_rect = text.get_rect()
        text_rect.centerx = x
        text_rect.centery = y
        screen.blit(text, (text_rect))

    except Exception as exception:
        print('Font Error')
        raise exception


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You really need to try and narrow it down yourself.  Put in some print statements and find out roughly where the issue is.  If you can narrow it down, and have a question about what is happening in a SMALL section of code, show us that.

Comment: planet.value = planet.value - (planet.value * 2) could be re-written more clearly as planet.value = -planet.value

Comment: I think the problem is that you are adding it to the enemyplanets list, but then below that when you process the enemyplanets it is now in that list, so it gets added back to the playerplanets again. in other words it gets processed twice in one update. add some kind of flag to the planet to say that it has already been processed

Comment: Ok I will keep trying. I am currently trying to change all my collisions from collidepoint to pygame.sprite.collide_rect

Comment: @samgak THANK YOU!!!!> THAT WAS THE ANSWER!

Comment: great. I copied the comment to an answer so people know the question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are adding it to the enemyplanets list, but then below that when you process the enemyplanets it is now in that list, so it gets added back to the playerplanets again. In other words it gets processed twice in one update. Add some kind of flag to the planet to say that it has already been processed.